# Perform OR operation to all elements in array

Tags: swift

I want to extend Arrays of Enums: Numeric with a function OR() that ORs all element in the array.

This is what I came up:

```
extension Array where Element: RawRepresentable, Element.RawValue: Numeric {

    func OR(_: Array) -> Element.RawValue {
        return self.map{ $0.rawValue }.reduce(0x00000000){ $0|$1 }
    }

}
```

and this is the error thrown by the compiler:

> Cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type '(Int, (_, _) ->
>   _)'

I want use it in situation like:

```
    enum RendererFlags: CUnsignedInt {

    case software =      0x00000001    // The renderer is a software fallback
    case accelerated =   0x00000002    // The renderer uses hardware acceleration
    case presentVSync =  0x00000004    // Present is synchronized with the refresh rate
    case targetTexture = 0x00000008    // The renderer supports rendering to texture

}
```

or enums with other numeric rawValues, and then

```
let flags = [.software, .accelerated]OR()
```

Where is my error? Why the compiler is not happy with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Numeric` is not enough for your needs, you need `BinaryInteger`:

```
extension Array where Element: RawRepresentable, Element.RawValue: BinaryInteger {
    func OR() -> Element.RawValue {
        return self.map{ $0.rawValue }.reduce(0) { $0 | $1 }
    }
}
```

Also `OR` should be without parameters and you need to specify the type somewhere:

```
let flags = ([.software, .accelerated] as [RendererFlags]).OR()
```

However, this can be implemented easier using `OptionSet`:

```
struct RendererFlags: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: CUnsignedInt

    static let software = RendererFlags(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let accelerated = RendererFlags(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let presentVSync = RendererFlags(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let targetTexture = RendererFlags(rawValue: 1 << 3)
}

let flags: RendererFlags = [.software, .accelerated]
```

The `OR` operation is already implemented for you and the options behave like an array therefore you don't have to worry about mask operations.